# Are compound if statements possible with Struts2 <s:if> tag?

Tags: syntax, struts2

I have a page that will display one of two options for a Struts2 JSP.
The problem I am running in to is that I have have to continually nest my  statements because I cannot figure out how create compound if statements with this tag.
Currently my code looks like this:

```
<s:if test="%{caseDto.siteId!=null}">
    <s:if test="%{caseDto.siteId!=0}">
        <span id="validAcctSpan" class="goodMessage">
            <s:textfield name="caseDto.siteId" label="Account Number"
```

...

I would like to know if Struts supports a syntax of something along the lines of:

```
<s:if test="%{caseDto.siteId!=null && caseDto.siteId!=0}">
    <span id="validAcctSpan" class="goodMessage">
        <s:textfield name="caseDto.siteId" label="Account Number"
```

...

Is this possible? I'm open to other/better ways of performing the same action. I am still new to Struts2, so I'm sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use compound if statements with Struts2. Using `&&` operator is OK for it.

For OGNL, check this document: 
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks kamaci. That link is exactly what I was looking for!